# Django allauth scope SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS documentation

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, twitter-oauth, django-allauth

I'm new to OAuth and the `django-allauth` plugin, and so far it has been really hard to find proper documentation on the mentioned plugin. I have found many disperse help in some questions here, and have read some code from [the repo](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) but there are some things that I just have not found yet. Right now, im trying to populate my user object based on the `extra_info` contained in the `SocialAccount` object associated to the user. My problem is that I have not found extensive documentation for the setting SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS. So far, I have gathered some useful info (mostly from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/)) and have the following setting:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'email',
            'read_friendlists',
            'user_birthday',
            'user_about_me',
            'user_interests',
            'user_groups'
            ],
        #'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'auth_type': 'reauthenticate' },
        'AUTH_PARAMS': { },
        'METHOD': 'oauth2'
        },
    }
```

It gets most of the desired information from facebook, but from twitter, since there is not scope defined, it only gets the name of the user, but fails in getting the email, and some other stuff I would like to know.

Where can I find extensive documentation in defining this setting for all the providers, and, specifically, which are valid strings to place in the `SCOPE` list for twitter? How can I make twitter give me the same info (or close) that what I get from facebook with the previous setting?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `'SCOPE': ['r_emailaddress']` ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me :(. I even revoked access to my app to try to "refresh" the permissions, but I'm not getting the email in the  'extra_info' field. Also, I would like, if possible, extensive documentation on the `SCOPE` setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope related parameters are really provider dependent. You will have to look up the parameters and what is possible up in the documentation of the particular provider (for FB, check here for info on scope: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).

As for e-mail on Twitter: they simply do not hand over this information. So, your app will have to cope with that.

See:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4019

Comment: Thanks again for your response! one more question: where can I read about asking other stuff to twitter besides the email (the avatar or the bio, for instance)? is there any page with the scope keys definition, just like facebook has [this one](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/)?

Comment: @pennersr, Is it correct that key "SCOPE" can be applied to any social provider?